# PSWindowsUpdate File Not Found Exception

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-update

I recently updated PSWindowsUpdate from version 1.6.1.1 to the latest version (2.1.0.1) and when I try to run the script:

```
Write-Host "      Centralized Update"
Write-Host "================================"

ipmo activedirectory
$computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter {enabled -eq $true} -properties * -SearchBase "OU=Workstations, DC=contoso, DC=com" | select name
$Script = {ipmo PSWindowsUpdate; Get-WUInstall -AcceptAll -Install -Verbose}

foreach ($computer in $computers) {
    Write-Host "Running update on:" $computer.name
    Invoke-WUJob -ComputerName $computer.name -Script $Script -Confirm:$false -RunNow
}

Write-Host "================================"
pause
```

I get the following error:

```
Invoke-WUJob : The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)
At C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Update_Workstations.ps1:10
char:2
+     Invoke-WUJob -ComputerName $computer.name -Script $Script -Confir ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Invoke-WUJob], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.FileNotFoundException,PSWindowsUpdate.InvokeWUJob
```

The only edit to the script was to change:

```
Invoke-WUInstall -ComputerName $computer.name -Script $Script -Confirm:$false
```

To:

```
Invoke-WUJob -ComputerName $computer.name -Script $Script -Confirm:$false -RunNow
```

More details:

- The version of PowerShell is 5.1 (both client and server side)
- The list of terminals is correctly extracted from the "Workstations" organizational unit
- I can connect via "enter-pssession" to all the terminals without problems
- Using "Invoke-Command" instead of "Invoke-WUJob" run but fails at the time of download with the error "UnauthorizedAccessException"

What's wrong with the code ? before updating to version 2.1.0.1 it works fine

Comment: Did you verify, that `PSWindowsUpdate` is loaded, if you run the script? (you might want to add `Import-Module -Name PSWindowsUpdate`. Also, can you test if `Invoke-WUJob -ComputerName aComputerName -Confirm:$false -RunNow` without anything else runs in an interactive shell?

Comment: The problem seems to be the "Invoke-WUJob" command, it has the same error both from a script and directly from the console. However, the PSWindowsUpdate module is loaded correctly, using: `Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer.name -Script {ipmo pswindowsupdate ; get-module pswindowsupdate}` it shows the correct version (2.1.0.1).

Answer (score 2):

I was also getting the same error. By scratching my head for a day finally a found one power shell command needs to run on the target server before proceeding invoke-wujob
the command is *Enable-WURemoting*

Comment: I was running into `Invoke-WUJob : The request is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070032)` and this answer finally resolved it for me!

Comment: I was getting the error : [Invoke-WUJob : The network path was not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070035)] and the command above saved my sanity.